# How can I use two columns to create date forcasts - e.g use the alternative column if the main column is blank? (automated ideally)

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet which automates dates based on two columns. I would like it to mainly work of 'Confirmed Delivery (column P)' but if the date is blank can I automate a formula to use the 'Estimated Delivery' (Column O)?

So far I have:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(T3:T<>"",O3:O+5,""))

but ideally I need this to be P3:P+5 or if blank O3:0.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extra column Q which contains the value from column P if there is a value and column O otherwise by:

=IF(P1, P1, O1) in the Q1 cell and then drag down.

Now you can use column Q in your new formula.

Comment: Amazing, Thanks for your help!